# Show/Hide Dropdown Option Depend on Another Dropdown Selection

Tags: javascript

What i'm trying , I want to show Second drop-down option based on First Dropdown Selection-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#type").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 1 + "]").hide();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 3 + "]").hide();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 4 + "]").hide(); 
            }
            else{
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 1 + "]").show();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 3 + "]").show();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 4 + "]").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="2"){
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 1 + "]").hide();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 5 + "]").hide(); 
            }
            else{
              $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 1 + "]").show();
              $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 5 + "]").show();
            }
            if($(this).attr("value")=="3"){
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 2 + "]").hide();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 3 + "]").hide();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 4 + "]").hide();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 5 + "]").hide();
            }
            else{
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 2 + "]").show();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 3 + "]").show();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 4 + "]").show();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 5 + "]").show();  
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="type">
    <option value="none">Select Any One</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>

<br>
Dependable Dropdown Show/Hide
<br>

<select id="grouping_type">
    <option value="none">Select Group Type</option>
    <option value="1">group_1</option>
    <option value="2">group_2</option>
    <option value="3">group_3</option>
    <option value="4">group_4</option>
    <option value="5">group_5</option>
</select>
```

But it does not work , it's doing strange behavior.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your nested if-else combination is wrong. 
let check, if I am selecting "one" from type combo. the first if condition where you check value == "1" will hide the option but again,

second if check send back to else statement and its again set display property block and so on.

you can just show set display:block(.show()) for all options before condition check and then set display:none(.hide()) for specific options.

i updated your code . 
here is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#type").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
             $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 1 + "]").show();
             $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 2 + "]").show();
             $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 3 + "]").show();
             $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 4 + "]").show();
             $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 5 + "]").show();
            if($(this).attr("value")=="1"){
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 1 + "]").hide();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 3 + "]").hide();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 4 + "]").hide(); 
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="2"){
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 1 + "]").hide();
                $("#grouping_type option[value=" + 5 + "]").hide(); 
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="3"){
                $("#grouping_type  option[value=" + 2 + "]").hide();
                $("#grouping_type  option[value=" + 3 + "]").hide();
                $("#grouping_type  option[value=" + 4 + "]").hide();
                $("#grouping_type  option[value=" + 5 + "]").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion: keep different select boxes itself and hide and show based on the selection, The reason for this is options may not be hide and show in different browsers

Second suggestion:
use option group, may be help full to show and hide particular category things.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#type").change(function ()
    {
        $("#grouping_type").children("option").show();
        $("#grouping_type option[value='"+ $('#type').val() +"']").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type">
    <option value="none">Select Any One</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>

<br>
Dependable Dropdown Show/Hide
<br>

<select id="grouping_type">
    <option value="none">Select Group Type</option>
    <option value="1">group_1</option>
    <option value="2">group_2</option>
    <option value="3">group_3</option>
    <option value="4">group_4</option>
    <option value="5">group_5</option>
</select>
```

I think, u have your complete answer :) .

Comment: If u find this answer helpful, please accept it so that u and me can get some reputation